# Apache Spark - Generic method for loading csv data to dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to write generic method with three input parameters:

1. filePath - String
2. schema - ?
3. case class

So, my idea is to write a method like this:

```
def load_sms_ds(filePath: String, schemaInfo: ?, cc: ?) = {
  val ds = spark.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .schema(?)
    .option("delimiter",",")
    .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    .load(schemaInfo)
    .as[?]

   ds
}
```

and to return dataset depending on a input parameters. I am not sure though what type should parameters schemaInfo and cc be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I would reccommend reading the [spark sql programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html). This contains some thing that I think will generally help you as you learn spark.

Lets run through the process of reading in a csv file using a case class to define the schema.

First add the varioud imports needed for this example:

```
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter} // for reading / writing the example data

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField} // to define the schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection // used to generate the schema from a case class

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag // used to provide type information of the case class at runtime
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder // Used by spark to generate the schema
```

Define a case class, the different types available can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.package):

```
case class Example(
    stringField : String,
    intField : Int,
    doubleField : Double
)
```

Add the method for extracting a schema (StructType) given a case class type as a parameter:

```
// T : TypeTag means that an implicit value of type TypeTag[T] must be available at the method call site. Scala will automatically generate this for you. See [here][3] for further details. 
def schemaOf[T: TypeTag]: StructType = { 
    ScalaReflection
        .schemaFor[T] // this method requires a TypeTag for T
        .dataType
        .asInstanceOf[StructType] // cast it to a StructType, what spark requires as its Schema
}
```

Defnie a method to read in a csv file from a path with the schema defined using a case class:

```
// The implicit Encoder is needed by the `.at` method in order to create the Dataset[T]. The TypeTag is required by the schemaOf[T] call.
def readCSV[T : Encoder : TypeTag](
    filePath: String
)(implicit spark : SparkSession) : Dataset[T]= {
    spark.read
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        .schema(schemaOf[T])
        .csv(filePath) // spark provides this more explicit call to read from a csv file by default it uses comma and the separator but this can be changes.
        .as[T]
}
```

Create a sparkSession:

```
implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
```

Write some sample data to a temp file:

```
val data =
    s"""|stringField,intField,doubleField
        |hello,1,1.0
        |world,2,2.0
    |""".stripMargin
val file = File.createTempFile("test",".csv")
val pw = new PrintWriter(file)
pw.write(data)
pw.close()
```

An example of calling this method:

```
import spark.implicits._ // so that an implicit Encoder gets pulled in for the case class
val df = readCSV[Example](file.getPath)
df.show()
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for you help! Could you please just explain me in more detail this part: ...[T : Encoder : TypeTag]... and also how would one use(envoke) method loadSmsDs?

Comment: That part means that an implicit encoder and type tag are needed in order to use that method. The encoder can be imported from sparkSession.implicits._. I will update the answer later this evening.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code you've provided, but to be honest at the moment it's probably too advance for me :) Anyways, what I'm trying to do is invoke method loadSmsDs where I have previously defined filePath, StructType(using Encoders.product[some case class].schema) and third parameter that same case class used to create StructType

Comment: after sometime spent on trying to invoke method, I get the error: "notebook:1: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method newIntEncoder in class SQLImplicits of type => org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Int]
 and method newLongEncoder in class SQLImplicits of type => org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Long]
 match expected type org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]" any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have made some edits to the above. I hope this helps solve your problem and please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your comprehensive answer.

Comment: @SteveRobinson great answer! Thanks